# Как работает указатель на функцию char (*func)(void*,...)

Tags: c, функции

Есть задача- вызвать функцию при помощи указателя на функцию `char (*func)(void*,...)`. Я так понимаю,что этим указателем можно вызвать функцию с обязательным параметром void* и необязательными параметрами. Но что значит этот самый void*? Ведь параметр void по умолчанию показывает,что функция не ничего не принимает?

Comment: `void` и `void *` - не одно и то же. Не надо путать.

Comment: У вас же не `void`, а `void*` - т.е. **указатель**. На нечто не очень известное - потому и с типом указателя "*вообще*".

Comment: @Harry А что именно таким указателем можно передать?

Comment: Функцию вида `char foo(void *, ...)`.

Comment: Да что хотите. Массив `int`'овЭ например. Строку. Смысл как раз в том, что указатель просто на место в памяти, а что там лежит - это уже вы сами решаете...

Comment: @Harry Попытался передать char массив - выдает ошибку void* is not a pointer to object type

Comment: @Harry Попробовал по другому - пишет. invalid conversion from void* to char

Comment: Нужно выполнять приведение типов - `void func(void* p)
{
    printf("%s\n",(char*)p);
}

int main()
{
    func((void*)"Test");
}`